# How-to strip email and phone numbers from html input?

Tags: c#, regex, string

How-to strip email and phone numbers from html input ?

Before: "please contact me at email@email.com or email[at]email.com or by phone at 555 555 555"

After: "please contact me at [Replacement] or [Replacement] or by phone at [Replacement]"

Comment: An example of before + after would help.

Comment: Does tagging the question with `regular-expressions` suggests that you are looking only for a regex solution? Also without providing the actual HTML and the format you are expecting it is very doubtful you will get any answer.

Comment: not necesseraly, but a regex solution is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use Regular expressions to parse HTML. See [this classic SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to see why.

You can parse the HTML using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) and once parsed this way you can use regular expressions to strip out the data you do not want.

Comment: ok, but how to strip out emails and phone numbers using HTML Agility Pack so ?